# Gradle installDist include some dependencies (and transitives) and exclude others

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Gradle build for a Java project.

I want some of my `implementation` dependencies (including transitives) included in the distribution `installDist` and others excluded. I want both included on the compileClasspath and runtimeClasspath.

Is the cleanest way to achieve this to customize the default "main" distribution? Or define a new distribution? Can I see the Kotlin script used to define the normal main distribution, so that I know how to create a custom variant?

How would I mark some dependencies as to be included or excluded? I presume I would need to declare a new Gradle configuration that is something like this:

```kotlin
val productionImplementation by configurations.creating {
    extendsFrom(configurations.implementation.get())
}
```

However, when I do that, dependencies tagged as productionImplementation rather than implementation aren't included in compileClasspath and runtimeClasspath.

How do I solve this?